# Derivative as a Linear transformation.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I like to know good books of calculus which are perfect for studying derivative as a linear transformation. I have W.Rudin mathematics analysis book. It has small portion of derivative as a linear transformation. Please suggest me good book for the same which are rich in examples and exceries. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The fact that the derivative is a linear operator on functions just means that for functions $f, g$ and constants $a,b$, we have $D(af+bg) = aDf+bDg$.  What more is there to know about it?

Comment: only this is not sufficient ....

Comment: @got it--thanks I guess, the OP asks about the definition of the derivative as a linear approximation to the function (i.e the Gateaux derivative) and not about the linearity of the derivative as an operator.

Comment: Probably the Frechet derivative rather that the Gateaux derivative.

Comment: have you found a book that examines in detail the derivative as a linear transformation?